# Discord bot Ignore Caps function Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using node.js to create my discord bot and I relatively new to coding. Currently my bot uses If functions to process input from members of my server. However I have looked and tried many things but I still cant seem to get my arguments to ignore the case sensitivity. Below is an example of one of the if statements my bot uses. If someone could guide me on how I could make it that my bot will accept both >Help and >help as the same thing that would be simply amazing!

```
  if (message.content('>Help')) {
  message.channel.send('Need Help? Ask a moderator')
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
 if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '>help')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I have tried that and it does not help D:   if (message.content.toLowerCase() === ">Help") {
      message.channel.send('Need Help? Ask a moderator')
  }